# How to prevent logging to file and capture logs for assertions using Pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a suite of unit tests for a python module and use Pytest to run those tests. I am now starting to use the standard logging library in my library and would need help solving two issues:

1. **How to prevent logs into files when running the test suite**, to prevent files growing and to prevent unhelpful entries in real log files.
2. **How to capture the logs inside unit tests**, to be able to run assertions on the logs that the library generates.

The module that I am trying to test configures the logging library in `__init__.py` to log into a file  and logs entries in the module code using the info method. That works fine and when I run the code the right log entries appear in the file ok. *-- see code below --*

I have tried to use the `caplog` fixture in pytest *-- see code and output below --* but the effect I get is:

- **log entries are included into the file** (logs generated in the runs from the test using caplog and all other tests)
- **`caplog.text` is empty**

---

#### Unit Tests Code

```
import library.module

class TestFunction:

    def test_something_else(self):
        library.module.function():
        assert True

    def test_logs(self,caplog)
        library.module.function():
        assert "desired" in caplog.text
```

#### Test Output

```
(...)
>     assert "desired" in caplog.text
E     AssertionError: assert 'desired' in ''
E      + where '' = <_pytest.logging.LogCaptureFixture object at (...).text
(...)
```

#### Log entries after running test suite

```
2021-12-07 11:10:05,915 - library.module - INFO - desired
2021-12-07 11:10:05,917 - library.module - INFO - desired
```

#### Logging module configuration

**`__init__.py`**

```
import logging.config
import yaml

with open("logging.yaml") as f:
    conf_dict = yaml.safe_load(f)
    logging.config.dictConfig(conf_dict)
```

**`logging.yaml`**

```
version: 1
formatters:
    simple:
        format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:    
    training:
        class: logging.FileHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: simple
        filename: logs/test_log
loggers:
    library.module:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [training]
        propagate: no
root:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: []
```

#### Module under test

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def function():
    logger.info("desired")
```

#### File Structure

```
.
├── library
│   ├── module.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── tests
│   └── test_module.py
└── logs
    └── test_log
```

Comment: I have been able to solve the second issue. The test now captures the log entry correctly and caplog.text contains the right text. The error was in the configuration, where the ```library.module``` logger was set to ```propagate: no``` and by setting it to yes the test and caplog.text are working fine. But **the first issue is still happening and every time I run my unit tests the log file gets log entries that I would rather not be there**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid writing to the log file, I suggest that, in `test_module.py`, you simply mock the logger and use it in your test, like this:

```py
import pytest
import library.module

@pytest.fixture
def logger(mocker):
    return mocker.patch("library.module.logger.info")


class TestFunction:

    def test_something_else(self):
        library.module.function():
        assert True

    def test_logs(self,logger)
        library.module.function():
        logger.assert_called_with("desired")
```